# Automated builds are broken in Azure Websites

Tags: deployment, azure, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-web-app-service

We had configured out Azure Websites to automatically checkout from TFS and make deployments. Suddenly the deploys stopped working. Most messages say "unable to connect to the remote server"

I opened the build definition and on the "Build Defaults" Staging Location, the option selected is "Copy build output to the following drop folder" and the option on the textbox is "/#"

This is the option that appears by default when making the link between TFS and Azure, but with this option turned on I cannot save the build definition. If I select the option "does not copy output files to a drop folder" then the build breaks/doesn't deploy.

Any ideas how to fix this? We haven't changed anything, it just stopped working today. If I delete all the build definitions and make the link from TFS again the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Team Foundation Service?  There is a problem with the hosted build service today - http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/current-service-status

Comment: Thanks. I panicked and though had screwed something up. Called support and couldn't get an answer (I'm going to subscribe to their RSS feed)

Comment: Don't know if this counts as a valid question/answer since it's related to an outage :s